# Accessing Scala nested objects through reflection

Tags: scala, inner-classes

I've got some nested objects like this:

```
object Routes {
  object admin {
    def home = "/admin/home/"
    def module(m:Module) = "/admin/module/"+m.code
  }
}
```

Accessible via `Routes.admin.module(mymod)` and so on.

Given the Routes object, I want to be able to access the admin object by its name "admin", in order to expose it to the templating engine I'm using (Freemarker). This is the solution based on the standard Java Reflection API I've come up with that seems to work:

```
val obj = Routes
val key = "admin"
Class.forName(obj.getClass.getName+key+"$").getField("MODULE$").get(null)
```

This finds for the static field `Routes$admin$.MODULE$` which is where the singleton object lives. Is there a neater way that doesn't require embedding knowledge of the naming conventions for Scala bytecode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the new [Reflection API](http://www.scala-lang.org/archives/downloads/distrib/files/nightly/docs/library/index.html#package) in Scala 2.10M4 this can be done with:

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.{universe => u}
val t = u.typeOf[Routes.type]
val adminName = u.newTermName("admin")
val admin = t.member(adminName)
// work with admin
```

Comment: After changing `members` to `member` I've acquired a mirror.Symbol representing Routes.admin - now to figure out how to get from that to the actual object.

Comment: Although I haven't worked out how to get from a Symbol to anything useful, I've accepted your answer as the reflect API is no doubt the way to do it in future.